# how to compare a specific part of a field between two files

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I'm struggling with the following task of comparing parts of a field ($3) between two files with tab separated fields. The files match for the other fields $1-2 line for line but $3 is subtly different. I'm only interested in one part of $3, the numerical value for **AF**. All the sub-fields(?) in $3 are separated by semi-colons but as you can see, the **AF** values aren't always in the position (sometimes it's #2, sometimes #3). I'd like to pull out lines where the values for **AF** in the third field are different between the files.

For instance, here's example file1:

```
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AB=0.743;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19066   AB=0.684;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19074   AB=0.321;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19212   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=382;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=342;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19384   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=400;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19395   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=398;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19461   AB=0.524;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19472   AB=0.527;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=0.936;DP=$
```

and example file2:

```
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AB=0.730;AC=4;**AF=1.00**;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19066   AB=0.742;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19074   AB=0.345;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19212   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=1.722;DP=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AC=8;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=1.721;DP=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19384   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=1.458;DP=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19395   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=391;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19461   AB=0.510;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19472   AB=0.526;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AC=8;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=-1.732;DP$
```

The output I'd like to get is the following lines from file1:

```
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AB=0.743;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=342;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=0.936;DP=$
```

or even something like this:

```
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AF=0.50  
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AF=1.00  
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AF=1.00
```

I tried to use awk but I couldn't figure out how to compare parts of fields instead of whole fields. I finally figured out how to use regular expressions to find the value for AF in each line from one file but don't know how to capture the value to compare it to another value from another file. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @C2H5OH Each file is around 900,000 lines long, 250M in size.

Comment: Excellent first post, +1 for sample data, expected output, great formatting, etc! but it's not clear why you are choosing to print the `19475 AF=1.00` VS the `19475 AF=0.50` record. How do you decide which one is the 'right' value? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: I think they are the ones in the first file, when they differ from the second file.

Comment: @C2H5OH : yes seems likely. Thanks for that insight.

Comment: @shelter yup, they're from the first file, once I get it to work in one direction I figured it'd be easy to flip it and get the lines from the second file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AWK array as a hash table to store the first occurrence of an **AF** value, then compare it with the next occurrence:

```
BEGIN { store[0] = 0 }
{
    key = $1 "-" $2
    match($3, /AF=[^;*]+/)
    val = substr($3, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-3)
    if ((key in store) && (store[key] != val))
        print $1,$2,"AF=" store[key]
    else
        store[key] = val
}
```

However, the filter-then-diff solution seems more elegant, because this one has the potential of consuming plenty of memory.

Comment: Nice use of match and store arr! I'd add sample output to highlight the fact that your solution requires 1 process, not 3+ as my solution. Good luck to all.

Comment: @C2H2OH Thank you, this works as well! I have access to a pretty fast machine so it didn't take more than one sec (sys) to run the awk script on my full length files.

Answer (score 4):

The following command should give you each file in the desired format. Then you could just do a diif on them...

```
awk '{s=$0; split(s, a, "AF="); split(a[1], a1); split(a[2], a2, ";"); print a1[1] " " a1[2] " AF=" a2[1]}'
```

Comment: Thanks @amit_g, this works! But instead of diff, it seems using comm -1 -3 and then comm -2 -3 would give the lines I want (I couldn't get it to work with diff, might be missing something).

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach

```
awk '{subList=$3; 
 sub(/.*AF=/, "AF=", subList); sub(/;.*$/, "", subList)
 print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" subList}'  awkTest_20120409_1.txt > awkTest_20120409_1_cln.txt

awk '{subList=$3; 
 sub(/.*AF=/, "AF=", subList); sub(/;.*$/, "", subList)
 print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" subList}'  awkTest_20120409_2.txt > awkTest_20120409_2_cln.txt

diff awkTest_20120409_1_cln.txt awkTest_20120409_2_cln.txt | grep '^<' | sed 's/< //'
```

** output **

```
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AF=0.50
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AF=1.00
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AF=1.00
```

Of course, you'll need to substitute your fileNames as input and output, and the targets of `diff`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

TXR: Created for molecular biologists working with crummy text files. And others people too.

Because the files could be huge, we avoid retaining anything in memory from one pair of lines to the next (ensured by the `:vars ()` in the collect clause).

A bit of a trick is used here to make two files appear to be a single stream, with interleaved lines. We can then pattern match over that stream as if it were one file.

The variables (column 3 material) are parsed into Lisp association lists so we can use `assoc` to look up the value of the field of interest. It is compared string-wise; if necessary a conversion to a numeric value can be done so that 0.5 and 0.50 are considered the same.

```
@(next :args)
@(cases)
@file1
@file2
@(or)
@  (throw error "two file names needed")
@(end)
@;
@; functional programming trick: make a bottomless lazy list which returns
@; strings, which are the lines from files f1 and f2, alternating.
@;
@(do (defun make-interleaved-lazy-stream (f1 f2)
       (let ((streams '#(,(open-file f1 "r") ,(open-file f2 "r"))))
         (let ((toggle 0) line)
           (gen (prog1
                  (set line (get-line [streams toggle]))
                  (set toggle (- 1 toggle)))
                line)))))
@(define parse-line (gen id alist))
@gen @id @(coll)@{var /[A-Z]+/}=@val;@(end)
@  (bind alist @[mapcar cons var val])
@(end)
@(next :list @(make-interleaved-lazy-stream file1 file2))
@(collect :vars ())
@  (cases)
@    (parse-line gen id alist1)
@    (parse-line gen id alist2)
@  (or)
@    (throw error `assumption violated: mismatching lines between @file1 and @file2`)
@  (end)
@  (do (let ((AF1 (cdr (assoc "AF" alist1)))
             (AF2 (cdr (assoc "AF" alist2))))
         (if (not (equal AF1 AF2))
           (put-string `@{gen 30} @{id -6}   AF1=@AF1\n`))))
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr gendiff.txr file1 file2
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AF1=0.50
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AF1=1.00
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AF1=1.00
```

Comment: +1 for TXR.  Just had a look into it. All my respect for (fellow) proglang -design enthusiasts! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might help -

```
awk -F'[; =]' '
NR==FNR{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="AF") b[++x]=$(i+1); c[x]=$0; next } 
{for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) if ($j=="AF") d[++y]=$(j+1)} 
END {for (z=1;z<=length(b);z++) if (b[z]!=d[z]) print c[z]}' f1 f2
```

#### File 1:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f1
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AB=0.743;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19066   AB=0.684;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19074   AB=0.321;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19212   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=382;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=342;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19384   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=400;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19395   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=398;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19461   AB=0.524;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19472   AB=0.527;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=0.936;DP=$
```

#### File 2:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f2
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AB=0.730;AC=4;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19066   AB=0.742;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19074   AB=0.345;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19212   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=1.722;DP=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AC=8;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=1.721;DP=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19384   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=1.458;DP=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19395   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=391;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19461   AB=0.510;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19472   AB=0.526;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AC=8;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=-1.732;DP$
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F'[; =]' '
NR==FNR{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="AF") b[++x]=$(i+1); c[x]=$0; next } 
{for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) if ($j=="AF") d[++y]=$(j+1)} 
END {for (z=1;z<=length(b);z++) if (b[z]!=d[z]) print c[z]}' f1 f2
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       18984   AB=0.743;AC=4;AF=0.50;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19285   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;DP=342;DS;Dels=0.00;FS$
dmel_mitochondrion_genome       19475   AC=8;AF=1.00;AN=8;BaseQRankSum=0.936;DP=$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk -vfile2=file2 -vOFS='\t' '{sub(/.*AF=[^0-9.-]*/,"",$3);sub(/[^0-9.-]+.*/,"",$3);getline line <file2;sub(/.*AF=[^0-9.-]*/,"",line);sub(/[^0-9.-]+.*/,"",line)};$3!=line{$3="AF="$3;print}' file1
```

Since `file1` and `file2` match except on the `AF` values:

- Read a line of `file1`
- Reduce `$3` to `AF` value
- Read a line of `file2` into a variable `line`
- Reduce `line` to `AF` value
- Compare `$3` to `line` and output `$0` from `file1` (after prepending `$3` with `AF=`) if they don't match.